# Public profile returning {"id":"private"} on API call

Tags: linkedin-api

we are doing this api call:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:8zM1yf0EJx)

and it's returning:
{"id":"private"}

the profile is actually public, [like shown on this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkPIo.png)

and the token or api key we are using is actually from the same user

also note, that the same process works fine for many other users we have except this one. These are the scopes we have for this (rw_organization_admin,r_liteprofile,r_organization_social)

we would like to understand why is it returning private when it's not

Thank you,

Comment: Did you find an explaination for this in the mean time?

Comment: Did you check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217550/linkedin-api-how-to-explain-private-connections